# Calculating duration of behavior states based on timestamps in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset on animal behavior, and I'm trying to calculate the percentage of time an animal spends in each of a few different 'states' (here, represented in the character variable `Observation` describing proximity to a partner: out of arm's reach, within arm's reach, or in contact). Each observation period is one hour long; observations from the same period are demarcated by `session` and `focal_start_timeStamp`. The column `behavior_timeStamp` provides the timestamp marking when the animal enters a different 'state'--i.e., it moves towards or away a partner. Here's what the first 20 rows look like:

```
structure(list(focal_start_timeStamp = c("2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", "2019-02-25 10:23:06", 
"2019-02-26 10:26:43", "2019-02-26 10:26:43", "2019-02-26 10:26:43", 
"2019-02-26 10:26:43"), session = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), actor = c("SIE", 
"BER", "SIE", "SIE", "SIE", "SIE", "BER", "SIE", "BER", "SIE", 
"SIE", "SIE", "SIE", "BER", "SIE", "SIE", "BER", "SIE", "SIE", 
"BER"), behavior_timeStamp = c("2019-02-25 10:23:28", "2019-02-25 10:25:19", 
"2019-02-25 10:35:52", "2019-02-25 10:36:04", "2019-02-25 10:38:12", 
"2019-02-25 10:39:32", "2019-02-25 10:39:48", "2019-02-25 10:58:34", 
"2019-02-25 10:58:48", "2019-02-25 10:58:52", "2019-02-25 10:59:28", 
"2019-02-25 11:00:18", "2019-02-25 11:00:27", "2019-02-25 11:01:00", 
"2019-02-25 11:01:40", "2019-02-25 11:02:13", "2019-02-26 10:27:37", 
"2019-02-26 10:29:06", "2019-02-26 10:29:12", "2019-02-26 10:29:28"
), Observation = c("Proximity_Approach to contact", "Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to contact", 
"Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Approach to contact", "Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach", 
"Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to contact", 
"Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach", "Proximity_Approach to contact", 
"Proximity_Withdraw to arm`s reach", "Proximity_Withdraw to arm`s reach"
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'd like to end up with is a summary table that shows the time spent, per session, in each of the three different proximity states: e.g., in a given session, the animal spent 5 minutes in contact with their partner, 20 minutes within arm's reach, and 35 out of arm's reach.

I've found some other questions answered about calculating the duration of states based on another variable changing levels, but those other solutions haven't been too helpful, as they took advantage of a numberic variable and used commands like `cumsum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are *four* types of observations

```
unique(DF$Observation)
```

> ```
> [1] "Proximity_Approach to contact"            "Proximity_Withdraw to out of arm`s reach"
> [3] "Proximity_Approach to arm`s reach"        "Proximity_Withdraw to arm`s reach"
> ```

but the OP asks to summarise *three* different states

> the time spent, per session, in each of the three different proximity
>   states: e.g., in a given session, the animal spent 5 minutes in
>   contact with their partner, 20 minutes within arm's reach, and 35 out
>   of arm's reach.

This task can be performed in 3 steps:

1. compute the `duration` of each `Observation` within a session (including coercion of 
   `behavior_timeStamp` from character to POSIXct),
2. derive the proximity state from `Observation`,
3. create a summary table of duration spent in state by session

Here is an implementation using my preferred tools (see `dplyr`/`tidyr` version below):

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
setDT(DF)[
  , .(duration = c(diff(lubridate::as_datetime(behavior_timeStamp)), 0), Observation), 
  by = .(focal_start_timeStamp, session)][
    , dcast(.SD, focal_start_timeStamp + session ~ str_remove(Observation, "^Proxi.+?to "), 
            sum, value.var = "duration")]
```

> ```
>    focal_start_timeStamp session arm`s reach  contact out of arm`s reach
> 1:   2019-02-25 10:23:06       1    120 secs 272 secs          1933 secs
> 2:   2019-02-26 10:26:43       2    105 secs   6 secs             0 secs
> ```

Although not requested explicitely, the result is presented in *wide format* with one row per session.

Here is also an implementation using `dplyr` / `tidyr` as requested by the tag:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(focal_start_timeStamp, session) %>% 
  mutate(duration = c(diff(lubridate::as_datetime(behavior_timeStamp)), 0)) %>% 
  group_by(add = TRUE, proximity_state = stringr::str_remove(Observation, "^Proxi.+?to ")) %>% 
  summarise(duration = sum(duration)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = proximity_state, values_from = duration)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
> # Groups:   focal_start_timeStamp, session [2]
>   focal_start_timeStamp session `arm\`s reach` contact  `out of arm\`s reach`
>   <chr>                   <int> <drtn>         <drtn>   <drtn>               
> 1 2019-02-25 10:23:06         1 120 secs       272 secs 1933 secs            
> 2 2019-02-26 10:26:43         2 105 secs         6 secs   NA secs
> ```

#### Edit

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707612/calculating-duration-of-behavior-states-based-on-timestamps-in-r/59712487#comment105594621_59712487), the OP has pointed out that the duration of the last state continues to the end of the session which is one hour after `focal_start_timeStamp`. Thus, the computation of `duration` needs to be modified accordingly by appending `focal_start_timeStamp` plus one hour as the last timestamp before computing the differences.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
setDT(DF)[
  , .(duration = diff(c(as_datetime(behavior_timeStamp), 
                        as_datetime(focal_start_timeStamp) + hours(1))), 
      Observation), by = .(focal_start_timeStamp, session)][
    , dcast(.SD, focal_start_timeStamp + session ~ str_remove(Observation, "^Proxi.+?to "), 
            sum, value.var = "duration")]
```

> ```
>    focal_start_timeStamp session arm`s reach   contact out of arm`s reach
> 1:   2019-02-25 10:23:06       1    120 secs 1525 secs          1933 secs
> 2:   2019-02-26 10:26:43       2   3540 secs    6 secs             0 secs
> ```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
DF %>% 
  group_by(focal_start_timeStamp, session) %>% 
  mutate(duration = diff(c(as_datetime(behavior_timeStamp), 
                           as_datetime(focal_start_timeStamp[1L]) + hours(1)))) %>% 
  group_by(add = TRUE, proximity_state = str_remove(Observation, "^Proxi.+?to ")) %>% 
  summarise(duration = sum(duration)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = proximity_state, values_from = duration)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
> # Groups:   focal_start_timeStamp, session [2]
>   focal_start_timeStamp session `arm\`s reach` contact   `out of arm\`s reach`
>   <chr>                   <int> <drtn>         <drtn>    <drtn>               
> 1 2019-02-25 10:23:06         1  120 secs      1525 secs 1933 secs            
> 2 2019-02-26 10:26:43         2 3540 secs         6 secs   NA secs
> ```

Comment: Thank you--this works almost perfectly! The duration calculations are still a bit off, though. The final proximity state duration in a session isn't counted, as it simply persists until the end of the session (one hour after the beginning of `focal_start_timeStamp`) and doesn't have a labeled end time. For example, the durations for session 1 should be 120 secs., 1525 secs, and 1933 secs. I could go in and manually add rows signifying "end of session" to make your script work as is, but is there a more streamlined way to do this?

Comment: @greben, I have edited my answer to compute the duration of the last state correctly. Thank you for providing the expected result.

Comment: This is magnificent. Thank you so much @Uwe!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do:

```
library(lubridate)

df$behavior_timeStamp <- ymd_hms(df$behavior_timeStamp)
df$focal_start_timeStamp <- ymd_hms(df$focal_start_timeStamp)

# get minutes
df$diff <- c(NA, round(diff(df$behavior_timeStamp) /60, 2))

df %>% 
  group_by(Observation) %>% 
  mutate(sumtime = sum(diff)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(sumtime = 0)) %>% 
  select(Observation, diff, sumtime)
```

Comment: Hi YOLO, sorry, I should have been more clear. The `behavior_timeStamp`  column contains all the duration information; the `focal_start_timeStamp` just separates different observation periods. Looking at just the first couple rows of my data as an example: I'm interested in a way to calculate that the first 1:51 in was spent "in contact": from 10:23:28 AM to 10:25:19 AM. Then, the goal is to do that for each of the three possible states.